# Selenium - Java - Extract text from site with no change in structure

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract data from a site, link below

```
https://bible.usccb.org/bible/readings/090120.cfm
```

**Code :**

```
String quote2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='block-usccb-readings-content']/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]")).getText();
```

This captures the text but my requirement is to write this to a text file and while I do so it comes as a paragraph, below is my expected and actual

Expected :

```
R. (17) The Lord is just in all his ways.
The LORD is gracious and merciful,
slow to anger and of great kindness.
The LORD is good to all
and compassionate toward all his works.
R. The Lord is just in all his ways.
Let all your works give you thanks, O LORD,
and let your faithful ones bless you.
Let them discourse of the glory of your Kingdom
and speak of your might.
```

Current :

```
R. (17) The Lord is just in all his ways. The LORD is gracious and merciful, slow to anger and of great kindness. The LORD is good to all and compassionate toward all his works. R. The Lord is just in all his ways. Let all your works give you thanks, O LORD, and let your faithful ones bless you. Let them discourse of the glory of your Kingdom and speak of your might. R. The Lord is just in all his ways. Making known to men your might and the glorious splendor of your Kingdom. Your Kingdom is a Kingdom for all ages, and your dominion endures through all generations. R. The Lord is just in all his ways. The LORD is faithful in all his words and holy in all his works. The LORD lifts up all who are falling and raises up all who are bowed down. R. The Lord is just in all his ways.
```

Wondering if its possible ?

Comment: if i am not misunderstanding your question it is printing in exacly same way if you do ***System.out.println(quote2);*** Unless I am missing anything.

Comment: Hi Rahul, If I have to sysout quote2 I do not get the text in the desired format, I get it as a paragraph. The reason being the site is developed like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the context with exact formatting by using below code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://bible.usccb.org/bible/readings/090120.cfm");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='block-usccb-readings-content']/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]")));
    WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='block-usccb-readings-content']/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]"));
    String str = el.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    BufferedWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\Download.html"));
        writer.write(str); 
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Hi Dilip, I thought about this but I do not want to write it to a HTML file, I need to write the content to a text file so this wouldn't help much. If you can think of other options please suggest

Comment: You want the text only or the text formatting as well? There few words are BOLD.

Comment: I only want the text, I have updated the question with my expected and actual. Please check

Comment: Instead of el.getAttribute("innerHTML"); use el.getText(); and save the file as .txt instead of .html.

Comment: el.getText() returns the text as a paragraph, I want it line by line

Comment: Atleast try, I am getting expected result. Check the screens : [screens](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ibCAyRqoS0w6Ik3xZg0JgXv3AE9Kat6T?usp=sharing)